# Do the variables used in computing the mean and variance have to be i.i.d.?

Tags: time-series, probability

For example if you have a theoretical server that processes incoming requests where in this case there are so many requests that the callback delays depend upon each other, can you just take the average and (sample) variance of the delays even though they are not i.i.d.?

Are there specific assumptions that need to hold when calculating mean and variance?

(I'm very well aware that it's a very stupid question, but I'm still uncertain about it and I wanted to know for sure)

Comment: You're always able to throw numbers into the $\bar x = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum x_i$ and $s = \dfrac{1}{n-1}\sum\big(x_i - \bar x\big)^2$ equations, so what do you mean if the numbers "have to be" $iid$?

Comment: For example when calculating a confidence interval you have a i.i.d. and normality assumption (maybe more correct me if I'm wrong), I was curious if there are assumptions like that for sample mean and variance.  I was looking around for what assumptions that needed to hold but I couldn't find any, to be sure I asked here.

Comment: Assumptions for what? I can throw numbers into those equations without knowing anything about them and get an output. How valuable those outputs will be is not clear.

Comment: I can do the same for the confidence interval, but the values I get wouldn't make any sense statistically. If I have a underlying distribution that constantly shifts periodically it also seems odd to just calculate the mean or variance over it as that wouldn't give any meaning full output.

Comment: So my question is more what assumptions need to hold for the output to make sense?

Comment: For example if I would simulate it m times for n requests. I have for each n requests m-1 i.i.d. extra points. So I could do do methods on there that have an i.i.d. assumption. But I'm not sure if I could just take the means over all n-1 request delays and then repeat the simulation m times, and that being a valid i.i.d. collection for the mean of requests as I'm not sure if calculating the mean has assumptions.

Comment: I'm very well aware that it's a very stupid question, but I'm still uncertain about it and I wanted to know for sure.

Comment: If you were trying to estimate population mean and variance, then dependence would often (and in the specific example, generally) be an issue for the variance. It's not necessarily an issue for the mean but it might potentially be if your sampling is biased.